# How do I preload items in a SproutCore ListView?

Tags: scroll, sproutcore, sproutcore-views

I've got a relatively fast SproutCore app that I'm trying to make just a tad bit faster.

Right now, when the user scrolls my SC.ListView and they scroll into view some list items that have not been loaded from the server (say from a relationship), the app automatically makes a call to the server to load these records. Even though this is fast, there is still a short period of time where my list items are blank.

I know that I can make them say "Loading..." or something like that (and I have), but I was wondering: **is there was a way to pre-load my "off-screen" records so that as the user scrolls, the list items are already loaded?**

My ListItemViews will be fairly large (pixel-wise), so even loading double the amount of data is not going to be killer from an AJAX perspective, and it would be nice if as the user scrolled, the content was always loaded (unless they scroll SUPER-SUPER-fast, in which case I'm okay with them seeing a loading indicator).

I currently found a solution by adding the following to my SC.ListView, but I've noticed some major performance issues on mobile and they are directly related to making this change, so I was wondering if there was a better way.

```
    contentIndexesInRect: function(rect) {

      rect.height = rect.height * 2;

      return sc_super();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding contentIndexesInRect is the way I would do this. I would do less than double it though – I might get the result from sc_super() and then add a few extra items to the resulting index set. (I believe it comes back frozen, so you may have to clone-edit-freeze.) One or two extra may give you enough breathing room to get the stuff loaded, without contributing nearly as much to the apparent performance issue.

I'm surprised that it results in major performance issues though. It sounds to me like your list items themselves may be heavier-weight than they need to be – for example, they may have a lot of bindings to hook and unhook. If that's what's going on, you may benefit more from improving their efficiency.

Comment: This is actually running on a "test" app where the `render()` method prints out some basic HTML that is provided in the JSON object (basically just a div with some text). They definitely aren't "heavy weight" item views.

On mobile, I can use `* 1.05` without a significant issue, but anything at like `* 1.1` or higher causes a slowdown.

Comment: Try going the monkey-with-sc_super()-result route and just add one or two actual items? (It's easy.) See what the threshold is that causes troubles? Also are you on 1.10?

Comment: It is indeed 1.10 and only 1-2 items won't show any issues as it's a scrolling issue (you can't scroll with only a few items).

I'll debug a bit further and see if there are any particular issues I can deduce.

Comment: I mean *adding* one or two items to the result of sc_super(). I'm trying to get you to switch from monkeying with the height of the rectangle to specifically controlling how many extra offscreen items get rendered. =)

Comment: Ah, I see. So, basically adding 100px if my list items are 50px high each?

Comment: No, go direct. sc_super() returns an IndexSet that you can manipulate directly (or possibly clone + manipulate + freeze, I forget which) before returning.

Comment: (For example, I wonder if you tweaking the rectangle, which is there by reference, is part of the problem.)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'll give that a try :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better served to load the additional data *outside* of the context of what the list is actually displaying. For instance, forcing more list items to render in order to trigger additional requests *does* result in having the extra data available, but also adds several unnecessary elements to the DOM, which is actually detrimental to overall performance. In fact these extra elements are most likely the cause of the major slowdown on mobile once you get to a sufficient number of extras.

Instead, I would first ensure that your list item views are properly pooling so that only the visible items are updating *in place* with as little DOM manipulation as possible. Then second, I would lazily load in additional data *only* after the required data is requested. There are quite a few ways to do this depending on your setup. You might want to add some logic to a data source to trigger an additional request on each filled request range or you might want to do something like override `itemViewForContentIndex` in `SC.CollectionView` as the point to trigger the extra data. In either case, I imagine it could look something like this,

```
// …

prefetchTriggered: function (lastIndex) {

  // A query that will fetch more data (this depends totally on your setup).
  var query = SC.Query.remote(MyApp.Record, {
    // Parameters to pass to the data source so it knows what to request.
    lastIndex: lastIndex
  });

  // Run the query.
  MyApp.store.find(query);
},

// …
```

As I mention in the comments above, the structure of the request depends totally on your setup and your API so you'll have to modify it to meet your needs. It will work better if you are able to request a suitable range of items, rather than one-at-a-time.

Comment: I think I'll try the `itemViewForContentIndex` route. Assuming I'm using a `SparseArray`, can I just provide more data to `provideObjectsInRange` or does it expect only the range that was requested?